# how nginx deal jsp file through proxy

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, nginx, proxy

Problem:create a hello.jsp file in nginx root folder.and configure nginx proxy well, but when i run `http://domain.com/hello.jsp`, 404 returns. Here i need to make a extra explanation, **there are nothing in tomcat/webapps folder, i cleared it before**.Maybe you think i lack ROOT folder in webapps, right! but it's not the point. when hello.jsp file cp to the ROOT folder and run the same url, ok! So i wonder how nginx dynamic proxy works? how such server deal with *.jsp file? will it cp its file into webapps/ROOT folder automatically or we need to cp such file manually? but it's ridiculous in the second way? So, what's wrong with me?

Comment: Can you show some codes? and elaborate the as well,

Comment: @Satys `location ~ /*.jsp${proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;}`I want to know how nginx deal .jsp file, whether nginx will transfer such file to tomcat ROOT folder or not.

Comment: it will forward the request to the server listening on port 8080 on the same machine, so if your tomcat is listening on port 8080, it should be able to process the request, so yes